# Difference between GeoJSON and TopoJSON

Tags: d3.js, gis, geojson, topojson

What is the difference between GeoJSON and TopoJSON and when would I use one over the other?

The [description of TopoJSON on GitHub](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/) implies the TopoJSON files are 80% smaller. So why not just use TopoJSON all the time?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If you care about file size or topology, then use TopoJSON. If you don’t care about either, then use GeoJSON for simplicity’s sake.

The primary advantage of TopoJSON is size. By eliminating redundancy and using a more efficent fixed-precision integer encoding of coordinates, TopoJSON files are often an order of magnitude smaller than GeoJSON files. The secondary advantage of TopoJSON files is that encoding the topology has useful applications, such as topology-preserving simplification (similar to [MapShaper](http://www.cartogis.org/docs/proceedings/2006/bloch_harrower.pdf)) and automatic mesh generation (as in the state-state boundaries in [this example choropleth](http://bl.ocks.org/4060606)).

These advantages come at a cost: a more complex file format. In JavaScript, for example, you’d typically use the [TopoJSON client library](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/) to convert TopoJSON to GeoJSON for use with standard tools such as [d3.geoPath](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoPath). (In Python, you can use [topojson.py](https://github.com/sgillies/topojson/blob/master/topojson.py).) Also, TopoJSON’s integer format requires quantizing coordinates, which means that it can introduce rounding error if you’re not careful. (See the documentation for `topojson -q`.)

For server-side manipulation of geometries that does not require topology, then GeoJSON is probably the simpler choice. Otherwise, if you need topology or want to send the geometry over the wire to a client, then use TopoJSON.

Comment: And even though I did remember reading about "shared line segments", I still assumed "topo" stood for "topography", which it does not. Here's a [nice read about the difference between "topology" and "topography" (the former is the origin of "topo" in topojson)](http://geospatial-solutions.com/topology-is-not-topography/) -- and I'll have to read Mike's article [here about inferring topology](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/topology/)

Comment: I would prefer to use [geobuf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geobuf) other than such hybrid solutions like toposjon when wire over the internet.

Answer (score 12):

TopoJSON is ideal for tidy features that "snap" to each other, like administrative regions, but doesn't help with more messy or organic data. If your data is simply points, then TopoJSON is no help at all.

Comment: Even when there is no shared topology, TopoJSON’s fixed-precision integer encoding can be substantially more efficient than GeoJSON’s floating point.

Comment: True. I'm wrong. I'd delete my answer, but we'd lose your valuable comment!

Comment: Ha, thanks. :) I've submitted a separate answer that includes additional considerations.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on many considerations. Among them are the following:

1) The nature (data model) of the feature or features you'd like to represent
2) Any attributes you'd like to have associated with those features
3) How you'd like these features to behave on the page (static vs dynamic)

However, this is a tough question to answer in the abstract. Regarding some specifics, if you have a contiguous polygon coverage or another situation where features are sharing boundaries, topojson's model allows you to exploit the redundancy and factor that into the model.

Read the documentation, dissect examples (e.g, bl.ocks.org), and then get some data and represent it in both geojson and topojson and create your own visualizations.

Comment: Thanks wsvekla. I have been doing that - I found yours gists on bl.ocks.org in fact (http://bl.ocks.org/wsvekla/4533258 http://bl.ocks.org/4348435) but not an easy one to google. However as you point out there are lots of considerations and I'm trying to explore side by side comparisons to learn this.

Comment: These two blocks reference the same original shapefile : http://bl.ocks.org/4485308 and http://bl.ocks.org/4348435. TopoJSON really started to sink in when I finally grasped how I could represent multiple features (national, departmental, and municipal boundaries) with the  same data in the same file (you can't do that with geojson). This is accomplished through the filter function: function(a,b){return a.id !== b.id;}). Try to understand that, and topojson will start to make sense. For better code reference and bare minimalism, see Mike's block: http://bl.ocks.org/4108203