# unable to visualize my geojson data with leafletjs

Tags: leaflet

all files load fine, I have the following lines to load my data

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0],2);   
var countriesLayer = L.geoJSON(test).addTo(map);
```

I have exported the shape file from qgis to geojson, with the above script 
I can view a sample geojson data but not this one. The CRS I'm working with is Adindan, can't tell if that is the issue. but my geojson data loads fine on mapshaper.

Comment: Hey! How about you share your geojson file with 1 feature? And also the code you have to load it into your file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fDlUC_qfAdUf1l06rZTmKgzK8s1Vp_v5

Comment: this geojson is huge. Possible cannot be visualized because browser will probably crash.

Comment: yes its large, i'm actually a newbie.... any workaround that ?   plugins for performance?  or a different library perhaps ?

Comment: In the past (2 years ago) I used CartoDB for storing huge geojson datasets. It is partially commercial. That means taht you could use it up to a specific number of datasets (10 if I remember correctly). You could store them in their cloud PostGis DB and then use their js api to render the dataset. Their js API, at least at that time, was built on top of Leaflet. It was an extension of Leaflet API. However, it has been 2 years since then and I have not followed the latest updates.

Comment: @EskindirAbebe What is your aim? To visualize all the data simulteanously? Or do you want to show specific data? Create an application?

Comment: @AntonvBR I have a web application I want to show/visualize the data on. I have 4 to 5 attributes and I want to provide an informational option on each parcel... and other options like searching and layering so it can be easily analyzed.

Comment: @EskindirAbebe Ok, yeah well if you have a server that holds the data and the clients only get a smaller sample of it? But yes.. looking at the size of your dataset you might want to look at having a SQL server of some sort. Maybe NOSQL with postgis?

Comment: @AntonvBR yes the size it the issue but storage is not ... I think I have found an exciting option with https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/d3MapRenderer/  and for matters related to the size a different format in TopoJson https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740705/difference-between-geojson-and-topojson  ... if you have an experience in these let me know. I will try it out in the mean time.